# AndroidManifest Error- /> error

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have an error on enclosing tag meta-data.
I have the following `AndroidManifest.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.meuprimeiroapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity"
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But it gives me the following error in `meta-data` tag:

```
Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I tried to close it with `</meta-data>`, but the error continues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a > here:

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Really?

Add a `>` after:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second activity definition, you are missing a `>` on this line, right before your `meta` tag.

```
android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity" >
```

Whenever you see syntatic issues, always take a look at the line prior for a proper line ending.

Even StackOverflow detected the issue - the code is not highliten correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `XML` syntax is missing a closing `>` on the 2nd activity.

Change this :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity"
```

for this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.meuprimeiroapp.MainActivity" >
```

---

Learn more about [AndroidManifest.xm](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)l